# Monotone analytic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\colon\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be analytic in some
ball $B$ around $a+0i$.

Furthermore, suppose $f\left(B\cap\mathbb{R}\right)\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ restricted to
$B\cap\mathbb{R}$ is monotone (in the usual $a\leq b$ implies $f\left(a\right)\leq f\left(b\right)$ sense).

If it exists, is the analytic continuation of $f$ restricted to $\mathbb{R}$ monotone? If not, can someone provide me with a counterexample?

Comment: You can always take the function $(x-\frac{a}{2})^2(x-b)$ for some appropriately chosen real value $b$, where $b\neq \frac{a}{2}$. Locally it can be monotonic for suitably chosen $b$. But globally it is not monotonic on the real line. And it is holomorphic over the whole complex plane since it is a polynomial.

Comment: Note that for these type of local problems you can almost always form a polynomial with the desired properties fairly easily.